# Using Flask, HTTPDigestAuth and redirect(), how do I keep authenticated?

Tags: python, authentication, redirect, flask

I know a very little bit everything here, but not enough to put it together...  I know how to do the following:

- Set up a Flask application with various routes
- Use flask.redirect() to redirect the browser to an external web-page
- Use requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth()

#### What I want to do:

I just can't piece them together.  My intent is:

1. When the user clicks on a link on an internal webpage (say the route is called "indigo"), it goes to my function at that route.
2. That route function would then log the user in automatically using hardcoded credentials.
3. I'd then want to return the html contents (`resp.content`) but make sure that the location was set to `"http://indigosvr.local"` and thus, all of the links on that page would be relative to that external page.

#### Faulty Code:

```
@app.route('/indigo', methods=['GET'])
def go_to_indigo():
  URL      = 'http://hiddenurl.com:8176/controlpage?name=Chez%20Private'
  Username = 'user'
  Password = 'password'
  from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
  getResp = requests.get(URL, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(Username, Password))
  return (getResp.content)
```

#### Results of faulty code:

The URL in the location bar stays as the old location (it's not redirected).  Every image link is anchored at the old URL location, not the new redirected URL.

What simple element am I missing?

Comment: Well, HTTP doesn't work like that. You can't login a client from the server with Diegest Auth.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe I'm not understanding you.  My browser is normally talking to SERVER1.  I want to hit a link on SERVER1 (Flask) and have the flask server hit SERVER2's w/ Digest Auth creds, and pass those creds back to my browser.

Comment: That's not possible.